# Removing Tap Event in a Frame in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a label inside of a Frame in Xamarin Forms.

```
     <Frame BackgroundColor="{x:Static resources:AppStyleConstants.HeaderColor}" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                <Label 
                    Text="{x:Static resources:Labels.ChooseProviderTitle}" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    FontSize="48" 
                    TextColor="White" />
     </Frame>
```

Now when I tap on it, I keep on hearing the tap sound. I am assuming that there is a default tap attached to the frame since after removing the frame, the sound disappears as well. I want to get rid of that sound since the clients think (clients are elderly people) that an action is supposed to happen. Can anyone suggest something I can do to remove the sound coming?

Comment: Could you try setting the `InputTransparent` attribute to `true`?

Comment: @Gerald Tried that. Still get that tap sound.